# ExtraTreesClasifier module 'sklearn.tree._tree' has no attribute 'DTYPE'

Tags: python-3.x, tree, scikit-learn, spyder, data-science

I used ExtraTreesClasifier in Spyder two weeks ago, now I am getting this error:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
```

> AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree._tree' has no attribute 'DTYPE'

I upgraded the package, but I still have the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? I just ran into it after creating a virtual environment and installing sklearn...

Comment: Actually, it started working on mine randomly after re-installing `scipy`, `scikit-learn`, `sklearn`, and `numpy`. I'm not sure which of these packages may have been the problem, or even if that was the problem, but after re-installing them (same versions), the attribute error went away.